# Text date to numerical date

Tags: php, date, text, numeric

I have this kind of results for date in my table EX: November 07, 2011, 12:00 am

So I need this kind of result EX: 11 07, 2011, 12, 00
How can I convert this text date to numerical date?

Comment: Is it posible to update my MYTSQL tables that are "December 25, 2011, 5:31" forumat , into "12 25, 2011, 05, 31" format with PHP. Some examples. thanks again

Answer (score 1):

check out strtotime() with date() in php, you may need to format your output a little though.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$dateValue = '11 07, 2011';
date('m d, Y, H, m', strtotime($dateValue));
?>
```

Please note that in it's current state, your date value may not be parsed properly by `strtotime`

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take on it:

```
function convert_date($date) {
    $components = explode(" ",$date);
    $time_component = array_pop($components);
    $date_component = implode(array_slice($components, 0, 2));


    return date("m d, Y, ", strtotime($date_component)) .
            date("H, i", strtotime($time_component));
}
```

Here are some runs:

```
   $t1 = "November 07, 2011, 12:00";
   echo convert_date($t1) . "\n";
```

Outputs: 11 07, 2011, 12, 00

```
$t2 = "December 25, 2011, 5:31";
echo convert_date($t2);
```

Outputs: 12 25, 2011, 05, 31

Comment: Is it posible to update my MYTSQL tables that are "December 25, 2011, 5:31" forumat , into "12 25, 2011, 05, 31" format with PHP. Some examples. thanks again

Comment: As far as I know, not in the format you want but you could use some other variations see here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html